# Whether to use or not to use: DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

In one Database table, created_at & updated_at are defined as:

```
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Updated At',
```

And in another database table, it's defined as:

```
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Created At',
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Updated At',
```

created_at -> stores datetime when the data is created.
updated_at -> stores the datetime when data is updated.

Which definition among above two would you prefer & why?

Comment: You shouldn't use `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` here. Otherwise it'll update whenever you update. This might be suitable for a `last_updated_at` column, but for `created_at` you only want `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Also, using a time of "0000-00-00 00:00:00" seems counter-intuitive. Is there a reason you're avoiding NULL?